# SG300/350 DHCP Snooping Configuration

Tags: cisco-sg300

I have recently joined a company who have Cisco SG300 and SG350 switches deployed on their network. I need to check if switch ports are trusted or untrusted for DHCP snooping. However, the option to check for this is only available on some devices and not on others, via IPv4 Management and Interfaces -> DHCP Snooping/Relay -> DHCP Snooping Trusted Interfaces.

How can I enable this feature on the other switches?

Comment: Check running versions. If it doesn't show up in the GUI, it's likely not available. Also, try the CLI to see if they just left it out of the GUI.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to enable it via the CLI.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP snooping is most important on access switches and should be implemented there first. Depending on your network design (especially regarding virtualization), snooping may be necessary on the distribution and core tiers as well.

If you use interfaces to establish trust for DHCP servers, those are basically the uplink interfaces on the access tier and the interfaces toward the DHCP servers on distribution and core.

Don't forget to authorize the alternative ports as well if you use spanning tree.